# Why does fdopen have a "flags" argument?

Tags: c

I'm never really sure what open mode I'm supposed to pass to `fdopen`, or why it even has an open mode.  Since `fdopen` operates on a file descriptor which may have previously been opened via a lower level call like `open` - which already sets the mode flags.

I mean, I assumed that any implementation of `fopen` would just translate the `char*` mode string into a lower level mode flag type, (an OR'd `int` on POSIX systems), and then pass that to `open`.

But if we're calling `fdopen` where we have an existing file descriptor that came from a previous call to `open`, why do we need flags?  It just seems to create more work for the programmer to translate the `int` flags into `char*` flags for `fdopen`.

Am I missing some use case where we might want *different* flags for `open` and `fdopen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to pass `O_RDWR` to `open(2)` and then `"r"` to `fdopen(3)`.  That is a perfectly legal thing to do.  Perhaps someone else called `open(2)` and/or `fdopen(3)` on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin shared the proper idea.

`FILE *` and `fd` are governed by different instances. since open modes are most likely being hard coded, so it's trivial for programmers to type it twice.

there are indeed some cases you will want to open something in `fd` first then wrap it to `FILE *` afterwards. for example, before i tried to provide a serial port interface in my own project, i had to open it using `open`, so that i could operate `ioctl`, `termios` on it, and finally, i wrapped it with a `FILE *` so that allowed the external world to use `fgets` or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the GNU documentation:

> File descriptors provide a primitive, low-level interface to input and output operations. [If] you want to do control operations that are specific to a particular kind of device, you must use a file descriptor; there are no facilities to use streams in this way.

Both file descriptors and streams can represent a connection to a device (such as a terminal), or a pipe or socket for communicating with another process, as well as a normal file.

The **fdopen()** function associates a stream with the existing file descriptor, fd. The mode of the stream (one of the values "r", "r+", "w", "w+", "a", "a+") must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor. The **fopen()** function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by path and associates a stream with it.

In general, file descriptors are not as portable as streams.

For more information check this link: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-File-Descriptors.html